# How to further optimize a pivot of a Spark dataset

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm using below code to transform the input data. I have around 70,000 input xml files and spark job is taking around 5.6 Min to create the pivot spark Dataset.

Is there any way to optimize it further?

```
String seqnum = "seqnum";
        Dataset<Row> atgXmlParse = spark
                .read()
                .format("xml")
                .option(rowtag, "RECORD")
                .schema(schema)
                .load(path);

        Dataset<Row> atgXmlExplodeDS = atgXmlParse
                .withColumn(seqnum, monotonically_increasing_id())
                .select(col(seqnum), explode(col("PROP")).as("PROP"))
                .select(col(seqnum), col("PROP.*"));

        return atgXmlExplodeDS
                .groupBy(seqnum)
                .pivot("_NAME", colList)
                .agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list(col("PVAL"))));
```

Comment: So your baseline is 5.6M? Seems OK, what do you expect?

Comment: just creating a Dataset itself , it is taking 5.6 Min. Can we apply an repartition on Dataset before  we do groupBy?.

Comment: The proof is in the pudding I would say. Try. Use explain. There are defaults.